# Grails mapping basic collection types

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, grails

Grails supports the mapping of basic collection types, for example:

```
static hasMany = [nicknames: String]
```

So what exactly is the difference between doing the above vs just adding an array (or list) of type `String` to the domain class - i.e.

```
List<String> nicknames
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that with just:

```
List<String> nicknames
```

Grails doesn't know that you actually want that mapped (via Hibernate).  Grails uses the `static hasMany` to tell Hibernate how to work without a need for Hibernate mapping files.

Technically, you don't need to define the `List<String>`.  You only need the `hasMany`. This will default in a `Set<String>`.  If you require an indexed list, then keeping `List<String>` along with the `hasMany` is fine as well.

Comment: When you say 'Grails doesn't know that you actually want that mapped', what exactly do you mean?

Comment: For example, when I define a non-collection field (like an integer, or something), Grails understands that I want it mapped and creates a corresponding column in the database.

Comment: It is different because you're talking about a column vs a foreign key relationship.  Grails needs to know what kind of relationship a collection has with its parent to configure things correctly.